# Entity Framework: One to zero relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've got

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser<int,MyLogin,MyUserRole,MyUserClaim>
{
     public virtual MyUserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class MyUserProfile
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My implementation of IdentityUser has INT PK. I want to have one navigation property in MyUser and don't have on the other side. I prefer data annotations. Is it possible to use IdentityUser PK for navigating? (EF v 6.1.3)

UPD #1.
Dependent type - MyUserProfile. And it DOES NOT have to contain navigation property of MyUser type.

Comment: Please clarify your intended relation... which side is the principal, which is the dependent. Is it required : optional (1:0-1) or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to mention a slight difference of my tests compared to the answer of @RudiVisser regarding the created database.

```
public class MyUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual MyUserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class MyUserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}


class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyUser> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MyUserProfile> Profiles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Profile)
            .WithRequired();
    }
}
```

Generated Migration

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.MyUserProfiles",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                FirstName = c.String(),
                LastName = c.String(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.MyUsers", t => t.Id)
        .Index(t => t.Id);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.MyUsers",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
}
```

In contrast to his answer, I don't observe the creation of a separate `MyUser_Id` foreign key. The `MyUserProfiles.Id` is correctly configured as primary key and foreign key. So anyone who wants to use such a configuration should give it a try but carefully observe the generated migration code.

My toolset: Visual Studio 2013, EntityFramework 6.1.3 nuget package.

Comment: Well, you're certainly not wrong. I just deleted my DB and generated another test migration which didn't have the extra key. I may have left my navigation property from Profile -> Users on last night. EDIT: Yeah that's it, you _can't_ have a navigation property back now without it generating another key or explicitly state the FK with data annotations. +1 anyway :)

Comment: @RudiVisser I'm always glad to hear when strange behavior originates from little mistakes and not from actual library problems ;). But you can have a nav property back. Just include it in the fluent api description, else it will be treated as separate nav.

Answer (score 2):

I'd question why it is you're doing this, a better solution may be to keep it on a single table as it will be faster unless they are both massive entities and the profile is optional (but even then, you could have a separate column stating that the extra data is or isn't available).

Since you seem to be asking for a 1:0..1 relationship you can implement it as follows. I know you wanted Data Annotations, but I'd really recommend being explicit here*, so that any changes to your model won't cause a potentially unintended knock-on effect.

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser<int,MyLogin,MyUserRole,MyUserClaim>
{
     public virtual MyUserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class MyUserProfile
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     public MyUser User { get; set; }
}
```

On your `DbContext`, override `OnModelCreating` with the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyUserProfile>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.User)
            .WithOptional(m => m.Profile);
```

** Full disclosure: I also always prefer Data Annotations over the Fluent Configuration Syntax, but I haven't avoided it to date and there's really no downside to it. For something as fundamental as this, you don't want it to be affected by a slight change in attribute.

This generates the following schema that keeps things lean as the IDs are synchronised between the two tables as we'd expect:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.MyUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Test = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.MyUserProfiles",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Test = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.MyUsers", t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.Id);
```

As @grek40 mentioned, it can be done without the navigation property on the other end by flipping the fluent configuration of the relationship (see the comment for more info), see grek40's answer for that option.

Comment: I just can't think of a solution, where the dependent `MyUserProfile` can live without a navigation property of type `MyUser`. So no matter whether it is fluent or data annotation, the important part of this answer might be, that the `public MyUser User { get; set; }` can't be avoided by normal means.

Comment: @grek40 indeed, is this a technical exercise to see if it's possible or a requirement? If the former, you _could_ do this via TPT inheritance, where `MyUserProfile` is a separate table, but is a superset of `MyUser`. Do you want an example of that?

Comment: Its not my question at all, I just read here and see that most answers fail because of the *"And it DOES NOT have to contain navigation property of MyUser type"* and you ignored it and thus succeeded in providing some sort of working solution ;)

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I read your question, I just wanted to post a complete working sample that could help for others also. I'm not sure it's possible at all without a navigation property but leave it with me... Trying something! :)

Comment: @grek40 HA I JUST REALISED WHAT YOU SAID. It's not your question! As in, it's actually not your question. Sorry. Still trying to think of another way!

Comment: @RudiVisser it's not a requirement, i just thought it's pretty simple, so now i'm gonna find another solution. Thank you

Comment: I think its `modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().HasOptional(x => x.MyUserProfile).WithRequired()`. The important part is to start the configuration on the side with navigation property

Comment: @grek40 that seems like it would have the same effect, yes, but it lets the IDs get out of sync. That may or may not be a problem for OP. I'll update answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: I don't have time for testing right now, so feel free to include it. The ID of the dependent will automatically become the foreign key to the principal in this configuration without explicit mentioning it.

Comment: @grek40 agree. Updated my answer to show the two generated schemas from test migrations. They're both functionally identical, but configuring it with the nav property generates a slightly nicer structure (ie. they share their `Id` property rather than autogenerated one).

Comment: @RudiVisser didn't reproduce your foreign key issue. See my answer for exact class definitions, generated migration and EF version info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm note sure if you want that, but you can "split table".
In other words use the same table for the two entities.

Like this:

```
[Table("MyUser ")]
public class MyUser : IdentityUser<int,MyLogin,MyUserRole,MyUserClaim>
{
     public virtual MyUserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}

[Table("MyUser ")]
public class MyUserProfile
{
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```